# how to integrate web application with website ? The details are given below

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, deployment, web

I Have created a dynamic web application. I want to integrate it with my website . Please tell me how to do this ?
Where to upload the Files?
The directory structure of my website ****ics.in is pulic_html is root folder.
To keep a note: I have war file of webapplication also

Kindly help me.. I want that web application to go live asap....

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: on my laptop im using apache tomcat server to run web application

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to deploy a javaee application into php runner. This doesnt work. You need a webserver to run it.You can refer https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-enterprise-linux/evaluation or Jelastic for the steps to deploy your dynamic web application. By the way u have free cores in the above mentioned sites to test ur application at free cost.
All the best